# Delete row from one table if I have a dependent tables and know value in the third

Tags: mysql, database

I know room guid (cda32057-b658-4660-a492-7d7838f7a692) in the table room. How do I delete the associated row in the image table (image_id 212).

image

```
+--------------+------------------------------------------+
| image_id(PK) |                image_name                |
+--------------+------------------------------------------+
|      212     | 62f07048-5080-4d05-a15d-dcc37df8b7eb.jpg |
|              |                                          |
+--------------+------------------------------------------+
```

image_room

```
+--------------+--------------+
| image_id(PK) | room_id(PK)  |
+--------------+--------------+
|      212     |      192     |
|              |              |
+--------------+--------------+
```

room

```
+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| room_id(PK) | room_name |              room_guid               |
+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| 192         | test      | cda32057-b658-4660-a492-7d7838f7a692 |
+-------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Perhaps delete from both `image_room` and `image` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
DELETE FROM image 
WHERE image.image_id IN 
            (SELECT image_room.image_id 
             FROM image_room 
                  INNER JOIN room 
                        ON image_room.room_id = room.room_id 
             WHERE room.room_guid = @__your_GUID__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM IMAGE  WHERE IMAGE_ID IN (SELECT I.IMAGE_ID FROM IMAGE I,ROOM R WHERE I.IMAGE_ID=IR.IMAGE_ID AND IR.ROOM_ID=R.ROOM_ID AND ROOM_GUID='cda32057-b658-4660-a492-7d7838f7a692')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to delete the data, in addition its better to delete the association data from the `image_room` as well

If you want to delete data for a particular `guid` you can do so as

```
delete 
i,ir from image i 
join image_room ir on ir.image_id = i.image_id 
join room r on r.room_id = ir.room_id 
where r.room_guid = '{your input}'
```

Now the above query will also delete the associated record from the `image_room` if you do not want that to be deleted then just remove `ir` from the delete clause and it will become as `delete i from ...`

Comment: I am using "On delete cascade" in my image_room table to delete from there.

Comment: So yes you can just use `delete i from ...` then.